# 7 segment LED displays

Tags: led, 7segmentdisplay, brightness

I notice the surface area of the decimal point in my 7 segment displays is only 1/4 of the ABCDEFG segments. Should I reduce the drive current accordingly, to achieve matched brightness? Can't find any mention of this in the datasheet.

Comment: I think it would be faster to just try it both ways to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The manufacturer will have made the brightness consistent across all segments and the decimal point with the same drive current in each.

Manufacturers do not specify a drive current for each LED in seven-segment-plus-decimal-point displays. If brightness was not consistent for the same current, they'd be giving themselves a lot of unhappy customers who were forced to experiment with resistor values.

You can prove this by trying it.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is no need, the brightness appears uniform enough. I suspect the LED dies in small displays are all the same but the light is gathered over a narrower angle for the decimal points and colons.

On very large displays that have multiple LED dies  per segment it is common to have fewer (only one or two) dies for the decimal point. This kind of display might require a different resistor for the decimal point if the driver is not constant-current because of the large voltage drop difference.

For what it is worth, where the manufacturer guarantees the uniformity between segments of a display of given rank the decimal points and colons are typically excluded. Despite that I have  not noticed any visually objectionable brightness differences when operated at the same current and duty cycle.

[image]